# Parse for words starting with @ character in a string

Tags: c#, parsing

I have to write a program which parses a string for words starting with '@' and return the words along with the @ symbol.

I have tried something like:

```
char[] delim = { '@' };
string[] strArr = commenttext.Split(delim);
return strArr;
```

But it returns all the words without '@' in an array.

I need something pretty straight forward.No LINQ like things

If the string is "abc @ert @xyz" then I should get back @ert and @xyz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define "word" as "separated by spaces" then this would work:

```
string[] strArr  = commenttext.Split(' ')
                              .Where(w => w.StartsWith("@"))
                              .ToArray();
```

If you need something more complex, a Regular Expression might be more appropriate.

> I need something pretty straight forward.No LINQ like things>

The non-Linq equivalent would be:

```
var words = commenttext.Split(' ');
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
foreach(string w in words)
{
   if(w.StartsWith("@")) 
       temp.Add(w);
}
string[] strArr = temp.ToArray();
```

Comment: Note: this approach requires `System.Linq` and .NET 3.5 minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're against using Linq, which you should not be unless you're required to use older .NET versions, an approach along these lines would suit your needs.

```
string[] words = commenttext.Split(delimiter);

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    string word = words[i];
    if (word.StartsWith(delimiter))
    {
        // save in array / list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const string test = "@Amir abcdef @Stack @C# mnop xyz";
        var splited = test.Split(' ').Where(m => m.StartsWith("@")).ToList();
        foreach (var b in splited)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.Substring(1, b.Length - 1));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```